# Remove class onclick anything else

Tags: javascript

This may seem like a really simple question, but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get it to work.

I have a series of elements spread across different parts of a page.

```
<span class="click-element"><span>
---
<span class="click-element"><span>
--
<span class="click-element"><span>
```

I want to toggle a class ("active") on/off on each of them when they are clicked individually, this should also remove the class from all the others.

To do this, my function looks like this:

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.click-element');

    for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
        targets[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            var clicked = this;
            if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
                [].forEach.call(targets, function (a) {a.classList['remove']('active');});
            }
            else {
                [].forEach.call(targets, function (a) {a.classList[a == clicked ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');});
            }

        });
    }
```

But what I'm trying to do, is then remove the class when anything else is clicked in the document:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
     document.querySelector('.click-element.active').classList.remove("active");
});
```

However, the problem I'm having is the second event seems to just override the first. How can I fix this? Or is there a cleaner approach to do what I want?

**No jQuery thanks**

Comment: You want to apply/remove class on all of the element at once or one by one (i.e. the element which is clicked that will toggle the class) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to cancle the event bubbling like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    targets[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var clicked = this;
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            [].forEach.call(targets, function(a) {
                a.classList['remove']('active');
            });
        }
        else {
            [].forEach.call(targets, function(a) {
                a.classList[a == clicked ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
            });
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Keys:

targets[i].addEventListener('click', function(**e**) {...
**e.stopPropagation();**...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.click-element');
var activeElement; // this should be some global variable

for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    targets[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

        if(activeElement){
          activeElement.classList['remove']('active');
        }
        var clicked = this;
        activeElement = this;
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
            [].forEach.call(targets, function (a) {a.classList['remove']('active');});
        }
        else {
            [].forEach.call(targets, function (a) {a.classList[a == clicked ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');});
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution will be to use event bubbling.
If you have a common container:

```
document.getElementById('#containerId').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    var element = evt.target;
    if(element.classList.contains('click-element'){ 
        //toggle active
         element.classList[element.classList.contains('active') ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    } else{
        //remove the active from all elements
        document.querySelectorAll('.click-element.active').forEach(
            function (clickElement, index) {clickElement.classList[remove]('active')}
        );
    }
});
```

In your case you don't have child elements in the spans, but if you had you need to check if the clicked element is a descendant of the span.

Answer (score -1):

try jQuery libraries it will make it easy

```
$( "span" ).removeClass( "yourClass" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/